# RTMP in Coldfusion10 - Type 'coldfusion.flash.messaging.CFRTMPEndPoint' not found

Tags: coldfusion, rtmp, endpoint, coldfusion-10, livecycle

I'm trying to use RTMP with Coldfusion 10 and the embedded livecycle ES.  The other channels and endpoints work fine, but when the server starts up I get an error complaining that the endpoint class cannot be found for the cf-rtmp channel.
I'm using the standard setup with no special configuration.

As I said, the AMF channel, polling channel, etc. work just fine, and there are no complaints about those channels or endpoints when the server starts up.

This is the error in the logs when the server starts up:

```
INFO: ColdFusionStartUpServlet: ColdFusion: VM version = 23.7-b01
java.lang.NullPointerException
      at coldfusion.server.jrun4.metrics.SimpleLoadMetric.run(SimpleLoadMetric .java:157)
      at coldfusion.scheduling.ThreadPool.run(ThreadPool.java:211)
      at coldfusion.scheduling.WorkerThread.run(WorkerThread.java:71)

Nov 21, 2013 9:34:14 AM org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationContext log
INFO: CFMxmlServlet: Macromedia Flex Build: 87315.134646
**** MessageBrokerServlet in application 'Adobe ColdFusion 10' failed to initialize due to runtime exception:   

Exception: flex.messaging.MessageException:
Cannot create class of type 'coldfusion.flash.messaging.CFRTMPEndPoint'.
Type coldfusion.flash.messaging.CFRTMPEndPoint' not found.
      at flex.messaging.util.ClassUtil.createClass(ClassUtil.java:70)
```

Here are the first lines of the rtmp channel definition in my services-config file referencing the channel and endpoint classes.

```
<channel-definition id="cf-rtmp" class="mx.messaging.channels.RTMPChannel">
<endpoint uri="rtmp://{server.name}:2048"   class="coldfusion.flash.messaging.CFRTMPEndPoint"/>
....
</channel>
```